# Google Analytics: createScreenView and createItemWithTransactionId in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I'm trying to update my Google Analytics code, I have found subjects about but all are different, in some files it's gonna work and not in the others, I don't know if I implement it as well, the part of the code:

```
/*******************************
 * Tracker écran
 ********************************/

let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker

tracker.set(kGAIDescription, value: "Demande Envoyé")

let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()

tracker.send(eventTracker as! [NSObject : AnyObject])

/*******************************
 * Tracker transaction
 ********************************/


var rangeName = ""

if let startRange = String(xml).rangeOfString("<Logement>"), endRange = String(xml).rangeOfString("</Logement>") where startRange.endIndex <= endRange.startIndex {
    rangeName = String(xml)[startRange.endIndex..<endRange.startIndex]
} else {
    print("invalid input")
}

tracker.send(NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createItemWithTransactionId(String(format: (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ApplicationUniqueIdentifier")!) as! String + String(id)), name: rangeName, sku: "", category: Configuration.MyVariables.typeForm, price: 1, quantity: 1, currencyCode: "").build() as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

The screenView is working, but I it an error for the transaction:

> Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'NSObject.Type'

Comment: Where does the error happens?

Comment: @Valentin for GAIDictionaryBuilder.createItemWithTransactionId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last line, you are trying to assign your newly created object to the NSObject class, hence the `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'NSObject.Type'` error.

You should create your transaction item the same way as the screen view so you should change your code to make it look like this:

```
let eventTracker2: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createItemWithTransactionId(String(format: (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ApplicationUniqueIdentifier")!) as! String + String(id)), name: rangeName, sku: "", category: Configuration.MyVariables.typeForm, price: 1, quantity: 1, currencyCode: "").build()

tracker.send(eventTracker2 as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Comment: And I can't solve the alert 'Cast from 'NSMutableDictionary!' to unrelated type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' always fails' ?

Comment: Since send take an NSDictionary, have you tried removing the " as! [NSObject : AnyObject]" part?

Comment: I already try sure it says: ' Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary!' to expected argument type '[NSObject : AnyObject]!''